# How can i show moving car in google maps(agm-map) using angular latest

Tags: angular-google-maps

How can i show moving car or marker in google maps(agm-map) using angular latest . If any one have working example please share me.
I have attached few sample one urls and i want implement same in angular latest.

```
http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip.htm

https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/xn8ss4zy/
```